# Azure AD Graph API add member to group

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add a member to a group using the aad graph api and I am keep getting 404.
A similar code works for me when I am trying to get the group members.
This is the code:

```
string requestUrl = string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/groups/{1}/$linkes/members?api-version=2013-04-05", tenantName, group.ObjectId);

string postData = string.Format("\"url\":\"https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}?api-version=2013-04-05\"", tenantName, user.ObjectId);

HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json"; //"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
webRequest.Host = "graph.windows.net";
webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}

string jsonText;
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader =
       new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    jsonText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I know there are other ways to do the same work, for example using the graph connection, but I prefer to use this way because it should work for roles as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your URL does seem to have a typo: $linkes. Should be $links.